# How to use `if`, `else` for checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery. Here, in my code, I have two check boxes. The check box one is checked by default. My problem is when I check the second check box it's displaying the text box and if I click first check box it's not disappearing.

The text box should be appear only if the second checkbox is clicked otherwise the text box should disappear.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.requirement-freqncy').hide();
 $('#post-buying-urgent').change(function () {
  if ($('#post-buying-urgent').is(':checked')){
   $('.requirement-freqncy').slideDown('slow');
  }
  else{
   $('.requirement-freqncy').slideUp('slow');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row margin-lft-right-0">
<div class="col-sm-4 pad-left-zero"><input checked="checked" id="post-buying-regular" name="optradio" type="radio"> Regular Requirement</div>
<div class="col-sm-6"><input id="post-buying-urgent" name="optradio" type="radio"> Urgent Requirement</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group requirement-freqncy"><label>Requirement Frequency</label> <select class="form-control">
<option>Please Select</option>
<option>Yearly</option>
<option>Biannual (Twice a Year)</option>
</select></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forcing a radio button to become unchecked by clicking another in its group will actually not fire the `change` event for that radio button - only the clicked one. What you can do instead is apply the listener to both:

```
$('#post-buying-urgent, #post-buying-regular').change(function() { ...
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.requirement-freqncy').hide();
 $('#post-buying-urgent, #post-buying-regular').change(function () {
  if ($('#post-buying-urgent').is(':checked')){
   $('.requirement-freqncy').slideDown('slow');
  }
  else{
   $('.requirement-freqncy').slideUp('slow');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row margin-lft-right-0">
<div class="col-sm-4 pad-left-zero"><input checked="checked" id="post-buying-regular" name="optradio" type="radio"> Regular Requirement</div>
<div class="col-sm-6"><input id="post-buying-urgent" name="optradio" type="radio"> Urgent Requirement</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group requirement-freqncy"><label>Requirement Frequency</label> <select class="form-control">
<option>Please Select</option>
<option>Yearly</option>
<option>Biannual (Twice a Year)</option>
</select></div>
```

---

Or, if these are your only radio buttons, apply them to the radio buttons without specifying IDs:

```
('input[type=radio]').change(function() { ...
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.requirement-freqncy').hide();
 $('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
  if ($('#post-buying-urgent').is(':checked')){
   $('.requirement-freqncy').slideDown('slow');
  }
  else{
   $('.requirement-freqncy').slideUp('slow');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row margin-lft-right-0">
<div class="col-sm-4 pad-left-zero"><input checked="checked" id="post-buying-regular" name="optradio" type="radio"> Regular Requirement</div>
<div class="col-sm-6"><input id="post-buying-urgent" name="optradio" type="radio"> Urgent Requirement</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group requirement-freqncy"><label>Requirement Frequency</label> <select class="form-control">
<option>Please Select</option>
<option>Yearly</option>
<option>Biannual (Twice a Year)</option>
</select></div>
```

---

Or, yet another option, change the selector to the name that they share:

```
$('[name=optradio]').change(function() { ...
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.requirement-freqncy').hide();
 $('[name=optradio]').change(function () {
  if ($('#post-buying-urgent').is(':checked')){
   $('.requirement-freqncy').slideDown('slow');
  }
  else{
   $('.requirement-freqncy').slideUp('slow');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row margin-lft-right-0">
<div class="col-sm-4 pad-left-zero"><input checked="checked" id="post-buying-regular" name="optradio" type="radio"> Regular Requirement</div>
<div class="col-sm-6"><input id="post-buying-urgent" name="optradio" type="radio"> Urgent Requirement</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group requirement-freqncy"><label>Requirement Frequency</label> <select class="form-control">
<option>Please Select</option>
<option>Yearly</option>
<option>Biannual (Twice a Year)</option>
</select></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only bound the change event to the urgent radio button, not both of them. Change your code to (`$('#post-buying-urgent, #post-buying-regular')`):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.requirement-freqncy').hide();
  $('#post-buying-urgent, #post-buying-regular').change(function() {
    if ($('#post-buying-urgent').is(':checked')) {
      $('.requirement-freqncy').slideDown('slow');
    } else {
      $('.requirement-freqncy').slideUp('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row margin-lft-right-0">
  <div class="col-sm-4 pad-left-zero"><input checked="checked" id="post-buying-regular" name="optradio" type="radio"> Regular Requirement</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"><input id="post-buying-urgent" name="optradio" type="radio"> Urgent Requirement</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group requirement-freqncy"><label>Requirement Frequency</label> <select class="form-control">
<option>Please Select</option>
<option>Yearly</option>
<option>Biannual (Twice a Year)</option>
</select></div>
```